# Remove ,"" and replacing '-' to '.'

Tags: r, regex

I am working with single cell data.

I am trying to match cell barcodes I extracted with another data, but the structure of barcodes are different.

Barcode I extracted: `,"SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA-1_1"`   (weirdly, it saved with a comma at the front)

Barcode I want: `SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1`

Which function is necessary to use when I try to remove <,"> replace these?

Comment: Have you tried gsub(',\"','',yourString)? http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

Data:

```
x <- ',"SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA-1_1"'
```

Solution:

```
cat(gsub(',', '', gsub('(?<=[A-Z])-(?=\\d)', '\\.', x, perl = T)))
"SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1"
```

Here we use 'nested' `gsub` to first change the hyphen into the period and then to delete the comma.

If you need it without double quote marks:

```
cat(gsub(',"|"$', '', gsub('(?<=[A-Z])-(?=\\d)', '\\.', x, perl = T)))
SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are some alternatives.

**1) chartr/trimws** Assume the test data `v` below.  Then we replace each dash with minus using `chartr` and we can strip all commas and double quotes from both ends using `trimws`.  If you have a very old version of R you will need to upgrade since the `whitespace=` argument was added more recently.  No packages are used.

Note that the double quotes shown in the output are not part of the strings but are just how R displays chraacter vectors.

```
# test input
v <- c(',"SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA-1_1"', ',"SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA-1_1"')

trimws(chartr("-", ".", v), whitespace = '[,"]')
## [1] "SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1" "SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1"
```

**2) gsubfn** `gsubfn` in the package of the same name can map all minus characters to dot and commas and double quotes to empty strings in a single command.  The second argument defines the mapping.

This substitutes all double quotes, commas and minus signs.  If there are embedded double quotes and commas (i.e. not on the ends) that are not to be substituted then use (1) which onbly trims comma and double quote off the ends.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('.', list('"' = '', ',' = '', '-' = '.'), v)
## [1] "SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1" "SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1"
```

**3) read.table/chartr** This also uses only base R. Read in the input using `read.table` separating fields on comma and keeping only the second field.  This will also remove the double quotes.  Then use `chartr` to replace minus signs with dot.

This assumes that the only double quotes are the ones surrounding the field and all minus signs are to be replaced by dot. Embedded commas will be handled properly.

```
chartr("-", ".", read.table(text = v, sep = ",")[[2]])
## [1] "SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1" "SAMPLE_AAAGCAAAGATACACA.1_1"
```